# Symbolic link to easily access folders on cloud storage return broken links of folders

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu-16.04, cloud-storage, ln

As I'm now using ubuntu, I've created a symbolic link to access my cloud storage files, saved on NTSF format in my former windows operational system.
So I've created this simple .sh document to address this files directly to my desktop every time I want to use them. It just suddenly stopped working. I don't know what it is. Any clue?

```
#!/bin/bash

#Creates a symbolic link to the NTSF cloud storage programs: One Drive, Google Drive and Drop Box

ln -sf /media/bruno/600CA3990CA368AC/Dokumente\ und\ Einstellungen/bmman/Google\ Drive /home/bruno/Schreibtisch

ln -sf /media/bruno/600CA3990CA368AC/Dokumente\ und\ Einstellungen/bmman/OneDrive /home/bruno/Schreibtisch

ln -sf /media/bruno/600CA3990CA368AC/Dokumente\ und\ Einstellungen/bmman/Dropbox /home/bruno/Schreibtisch
```

When I execute this code in the terminal, typping ./clouds.sh, it should create three folders on my desktop, with symbolic links to my cloud storage folders, as it was doing. It now creates three broken links. Sometime the script works, sometimes it just doesn't work and I can not identify what is causing this behavior.

Sorry for the naive question. I'm only starting with coding.

Thanks

Comment: "Doesn't work" is always a bad bug report.  Must haves of all bug reports: ① Situation and action, ② what was expected, ③ what was observed instead.

Comment: please update your Q as @Alfe recommends (don't reply in comments.). Thanks.